# Windows service can not access to smb shared file

Tags: linux, windows, share, smb

We have SMB share on linux,we are using domain credentials for mounting and i can read files without any problem, but software runing as windows service cant see mounted disk.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

we have fixed it, when you are mapping smb share from linux to windows, and in your software show disk letter, for example Z:\somefile.txt it will not read it, instead it map disk and write full path for exampla \192.168.1.1\shared\file.txt

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows services can't access mapped network drives. You have to use the full UNC path.  **\\**192.168.1.1\shared\file.txt in your example (looks like the editor converted your double forward slash into a single slash, as if you were escaping it- you can also use machine name instead of IP address).  Also, make sure that your service is running as an account that has permissions on the network share.